# Haskell + "Remove a parameter"

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming

I have a kind of theoretical question, that a friend and I have been trying to see, how we could do it. We have a function named `palindrome`, that tell us if a String is a palindrome. Here's how we implemented it (there are probably better ways to do it, but that's how we like it more.)

```
palindrome :: String -> Bool
palindrome = \x -> (== reverse x) x
```

What we want to do is to `remove` the Lambda we're using here and just work with partial application and high order functions. We have had several ideas of how to do this, but none of them matches with the type of function we made:

```
palindrome :: String -> Bool
```

One of the closest approaches was using composition, but it returns us a Function, that takes two Strings and not one, since one is for reverse and other for the (==):

```
palindrome = (==) . reverse
```

Maybe, we're forgetting something or we're not seeing something. How would you do it in order to use this two functions without using Lambda?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want a pointfree version or will `palindrome x = x == reverse x` do ?

Comment: I want a version where there are no parameters in it, just working with functions to get rid of the lambda we're using. All the answers look good so far. Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @DavidCorrea A tip for getting these sorts of reductions programmatically (albeit not always in an understandable form) is to use the [pointfree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) tool.  Just pass it an expression like `palindrome x = x == reverse x` and it'll return the most pointfree form it can derive.

Comment: http://pointfree.io/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got three answers right now but perhaps not so much understanding.

The *problem* is that you've got two x's on the right hand side, and it doesn't look like there's a good way to remove one. You need a function with one of the following signatures to "duplicate" that x:

```
x -> (x, x)
x -> (x -> a, x -> b) -> (a, b)
((x, x) -> y) x -> y
(x -> x -> y) -> x -> y
(x -> y) -> (x -> y -> z) -> (x -> z)
```

These are actually surprisingly hard to find; I would have imagined that the first of these would be available under the name `dup x = (x, x)`, but it's nowhere to be found. None of these are anywhere to be found in the Prelude, to my knowledge.

It turns out that there's a Monad called the "Reader" monad which threads one value (in this case your `x`) through many functions. This monad's *type* is `(->) x`, meaning that it's the functions `x -> y` for all `y`. The second-to-last function above `(x -> x -> y) -> x -> y` can actually just be written as:

```
Prelude> :m + Control.Monad
Prelude Control.Monad> :t (id >>=)
(id >>=) :: (a -> a -> b) -> a -> b
```

You could therefore write just:

```
id >>= (==) . reverse
```

or even more concisely:

```
palindrome = reverse >>= (==)
```

It turns out that everyone else's version secretly uses `(>>=)` behind the scenes. It turns out for instance that every `Monad` is an `Applicative` and the `Control.Applicative` library exports a symbol `(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (x -> y) -> f x -> f y`. In the case of `f` being `(->) a` we have: `(<*>) :: (a -> x -> y) -> (a -> x) -> y` which we can apply to `(==)` and `reverse` to get:

```
palindrome = (==) <*> reverse
```

Or `Control.Monad` has the same `instance Monad ((->) x)` and exports both `>>=` for it (as above, `(x -> y) -> (y -> x -> z) -> x -> z` and `join :: m (m x) -> m x` which in this case is `(x -> x -> y) -> x -> y`.

There are lots of options, but that instance declaration is made in those libraries. If you wanted to do it without those libraries you'd have to write out the tedious:

```
instance Monad ((->) x) where
    return = const
    yx >>= zxy = \x -> zxy (yx x) x
```

before you applied those functions. At that point it's almost easier to write:

```
Prelude> let dup x = (x, x)
Prelude> let palindrome = uncurry ((==) . reverse) . dup
Prelude> :t palindrome
palindrome :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
```

Comment: +1 for `reverse >>= (==)`. However, please note `f >>= g` is not equal to `g <*> f` but `flip g <*> f`. You can convince yourself using `g` = `(,)`.

Comment: Even 'tho all the answers are nice, I will choose this one as the correct one for all the explanation of each solution. It has been really useful. The Arrows approach is also very interesting as well.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `<*>` operator for the `(->)` instance of `Applicative`.

```
palindrome = (==) <*> reverse
```

The `<*>` operator is kind of like function application in some context. In this case, that context is "functions taking a `String` as an argument". So you get a function that takes a `String` and pass it to two functions that also take `String`s and then applies the result of the former to the latter. In other words, `f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `join` from `Control.Monad`

```
palindrome = join ((==) . reverse)
```

`join` is an essential function for monads. However, for this special case, which is functions (or to be more precise, the `(->)` instance of `Monad`), `join f x` just evaluates to `f x x`.

Answer (score 4):

A few more alternatives (albeit worse than the previous answers ;-))

```
import Control.Arrow
palindrome1 = (reverse &&& id) >>> uncurry (==)
palindrome2 = ((==) &&& reverse) >>> uncurry ($)
```

Comment: I've seen Arrows around the web and I must say it looks so interesting. I'm kind of new into the Functional Programming, and I'm loving it so far.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Control.Applicative`

```
palindrome = (==) <*> reverse
```

Comment: It's a typo, fixed it